# EmailJS - Send base64-encoded screenshot in webp format?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning to use EmailJS to send emails, and I'd like to use EmailJS to allow sending screenshots. How do I send a base64-encoded screenshot in webp format using EmailJS?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```html
<img src="data:image/webp;base64,---YOUR-BASE-64-IMAGE-HERE---" />
```

Don't forget to check the [support for webp image format in email clients](https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-webp/). It's not so popular

Comment: Do I add this to the EmailJS template? Or where?